# Multi series not working in Bar Chart in Recharts

Tags: recharts

I need to create a bar graph with one of the format below. data1 or data2

```
const data1 = [ { day: 'ABC', data :[ {job_name: "Mon", value: 4}, {job_name: "Tue", value: 5}, {job_name: "Thu", value: 18}, {job_name: "Fri", value: 5} ] }, { day: 'DEF', data :[ {job_name: "Mon", value: 12}, {job_name: "Tue", value: 15}, {job_name: "Wed", value: 18}, {job_name: "Fri", value: 8} ] }, { day: 'XYZ', data :[ {job_name: "Mon", value: 12}, {job_name: "Tue", value: 15}, {job_name: "Wed", value: 18}, {job_name: "Thu", value: 8} ] } ];

const data2 = [ { day: 'Mon', data :[ {job_name: "ABC", value: 4}, {job_name: "DEF", value: 5}, {job_name: "XYZ", value: 8} ] }, { day: 'Tue', data :[ {job_name: "ABC", value: 12}, {job_name: "DEF", value: 15}, {job_name: "XYZ", value: 18} ] }, { day: 'Wed', data :[ {job_name: "DEF", value: 15}, {job_name: "XYZ", value: 18} ] }, { day: 'Thu', data :[ {job_name: "ABC", value: 12}, {job_name: "XYZ", value: 18} ] }, { day: 'Fri', data :[ {job_name: "ABC", value: 12}, {job_name: "DEF", value: 15} ] } ];
```

Comment: Please try something yourself and then post a question.

Comment: Hi, I tried the below. But still the bars are not coming correctly.

Comment: <ResponsiveContainer width="95%" height={190}><BarChart data = {data} barCategoryGap="10%"><CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" /><XAxis dataKey="job_name" type="category" allowDuplicatedCategory={false} interval={0} /><YAxis type="number" domain={[0, 'auto']} /><Tooltip cursor={{fill: 'transparent'}} /><Legend />
            {data.map((s,index) => (
              <Bar dataKey="value" data={s.data} name={s.day} key={index} barGap={0} 
              fill={COLORS[index%COLORS.length]} shape={CustomBar} barSize={10} />
            ))}
          </BarChart></ResponsiveContainer>

Comment: shape={CustomBar} can be ignore. that was extra code

Comment: this was tried for data2 as first preference

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't. The shape of the data in your samples aren't suitable for Rechart.

Please look up the documentation of [Rechart - BarChart -> data](http://recharts.org/en-US/api/BarChart#data) and reshape your data accordingly.

Here's an example of the required data format from the same page:

```
const data = [
  {
    "name": "Page A",
    "uv": 4000,
    "pv": 2400,
    "amt": 2400
  },
  {
    "name": "Page B",
    "uv": 3000,
    "pv": 1398,
    "amt": 2210
  }
```

Where `name` is the x-axis data label, and `uv`, `pv` and `amt` are the values of the data series.

So a more hands on example:

```
const data = [
  {
    "name": "2019-11-01",
    "morning_temp": 8,
    "midday_temp": 14,
    "evening_temp": 10
  },
  {
    "name": "2019-11-02",
    "morning_temp": 5,
    "midday_temp": 18,
    "evening_temp": 7
  },
   ...
```

Though from my own experience changing the shape you have can be challenging and possibly will end up a high complexity function. If you can't change the data shape you may have a look at [react-vis](https://uber.github.io/react-vis/) -> [sample](https://uber.github.io/react-vis/documentation/getting-started/your-first-chart) as react-vis' data-shape looks more similar to your samples.

Either case the data has to be in the right shape.